# How to install PyQT4 on FreeBSD?

Tags: software-installation, freebsd, repository

I need to run an application that uses PyQT4 on FreeBSD 10. I searched ports, but could not identify any package for PYQT4. Which package will install this?

Answer (score 1):

It is in ports: `/usr/ports/devel/py-qt4/`. Or you can install a package `pkg install devel/py-qt4`.

[Source](http://www.freshports.org/devel/py-qt4/)

Comment: How come when I search for it in [this FreeBSD search tool](https://www.freebsd.org/ports/), it is not found?

Comment: Names there contain versions, like [link](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/ports.cgi?query=py27-qt&stype=all&sektion=devel)

Comment: Or you can install from package: `pkg install py27-qt4`. Please note there are many `py27-qt4-*`, so you'll need some other too.